# Initialize an array at specific offset using a structure, possible?

Tags: c, arrays

Say I have a structure like the following

```
typedef struct {
   char field1: 4,
   char field2: 4
} MyStruct_t;
```

Now, there is a large buffer of data that is declared

`char BigBuffer[2048]`

I want to initialize parts of the array using the structure defined above, how would I do that?

```
char BigBuffer[2048] = {
   [10]  = (MyStruct_t)(.field1 = 5, field2 = 7),
   [20]  = (MyStruct_t)(.field1 = 7, field2 = 4),
   [200] = (MyStruct_t)(.field1 = 1, field2 = 9) }
```

Is this possible or something similar?

I already have a different solution using #define with masking and shifting,

```
char BigBuffer[2048] = {
   [10]  = (5 & 0xf) << 4 | (7 & 0xf),
   [20]  = (7 & 0xf) << 4 | (4 & 0xf),
   [200] = (1 & 0xf) << 4 | (9 & 0xf) }
```

As a note, I am aware the packing of the bit fields in the structure is left up to the compiler unless a directive is used to specify.  Just trying to demonstrate the intent.  Thanks!

Comment: You can't do this. You can `memcpy` your structures later. But you can use a fancy `union`, which you could initilize with structures and access as an array.

Comment: Eugene, thanks.  I might image this was the case.  The structure is a small part of the larger buffer.  I would overlay them, but not too practical given what I was handed.  I was trying to find a way for the values to be found during build time and init as part of the crt.

Comment: Is `[10]  = (5 & 0xf) << 4 | (7 & 0xf),` legal syntax?

Comment: @EugeneSh. How should that `union` be?

Comment: @RSahu I think it's [designated initialiser](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).

Comment: @J...S Something like 
`union { 
 char BigBuffer[2048]; 
 struct {
  char pad0[xx];
  MyStruct_t s0;
  char pad1[xx];
  MyStruct_t s1;
                .........
 }
}`

Comment: @RSahu, yes, working in my code based though using #defines.  Though, this is a C99 feature, if I recall correctly

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks. Got it now.

Comment: In the end, I used the union method as @EugeneSh suggested.  Just need to test it out now.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I got your question correctly, but I still believe `(5 & 0xf) << 4 | (7 & 0xf)` is more elegant.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    char field1:4;
    char field2:4;
}MyStruct_t;

int main(){
    char b[2] = {
        [0] = *(char*)&(MyStruct_t){.field1 = 5, .field2 = 7},
        [1] = *(char*)&(MyStruct_t){.field1 = 7, .field2 = 4}
    };

    printf("%02x %02x\n", b[0], b[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice.  This works in CLion that is using gcc.  Unfortunately, the tools I am using for the project give me the error of "error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant" along with an error with the tools.

Comment: @lordhog Yes, it violates the standard: "The operand of the unary & operator shall be either **a function designator**, **the result of a `[]` or unary `*` operator**, or **an lvalue** that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is not declared with the register storage-class specifier." So it depends on the compiler.